# Ошибка "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in..."

Tags: php, циклы, mysql

```
$group = clear($_GET['id']);
$query = queryMysql("SELECT id FROM clients WHERE group_id = '$group'");

while ($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // СТРОКА 20
    $id = $c['id'];
    $query = queryMysql("UPDATE `clients` SET `group_id` = '0' WHERE `id` = '$id';");
}
```

Я никак не пойму, почему этот код выдает ошибку:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied
> argument is not a valid MySQL result
> resource in
> W:\domains\base\www\core\mods\groups\deletegroup.php
> on line 20

Comment: Проверьте выход функций `clear`, `queryMysql`.

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вы [не обрабатываете ошибки mysql](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php).

Вторая ваша ошибка, в том, что вы используете устаревшее расширение mysql, а не [mysqli](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) или [pdo](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Дело не в функциях

Comment: >Ошибка в том, что вы не обрабатываете ошибки mysql.
>Вторая ваша ошибка, в том, что вы используете устаревшее расширение >mysql, а не mysqli или pdo.

ппц. Причем тут обработка ошибок, скрипт явно написал что аргументы невалидны! Просто опять же никто не вглядывается в код, просто глянул, написал шаблонный ответ и все. Да Вот такие ошибки., кстати сложно отлавливать!

Comment: @Shrek, бред, ошибка MySQL даст подробней знать причину и всё станет понятно быстро.  
В конкретно этом случае ошибка в другом, но мускулевые ошибки нужно смотреть всё равно в общем.

Comment: 2 @Construc
>Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL >result resource in >W:\domains\base\www\core\mods\groups\deletegroup.php on line 20

Вот ошибка! В чем проблема? Бреда в моих слова нет, а вот мат.часть почитать советую.

Написано же почти по-русски даже глупый гуглтранслейт переведет.

>Внимание: mysql_fetch_assoc (): поставляется аргумент не является >допустимым MySQL> 

Это ошибка не Мускула Это во первых, во вторых это ошибка горе-программиста, который так пишет свой код. т.к. логически все написано правильно, но реализация хромает, причем сильно.

Comment: @Shrek, я понимаю, я и сказал, что в данном случае ошибка не мускулевская. Но это не значит, что их не надо смотреть.

Comment: Подробнее об ошибках.

Если сами пишем скрипты то тут уже дело вкуса и опыта программиста, можно и не отлавливать ошибки, если знаешь что до момента обращения к Базе ты их исключил.
а вот взять допустим Yii и там вот отлавливать ошибки нааааамного прикольнее.
**Cms Product Collections Tmp Code cannot be blank.** вразу говорит в каком поле и какая ошибка + название таблицы можно вывести, но это уже инструмент не для горе-программистов. а так, отлавливать ошибки БД, когда ошибка в другом - это ИМХО называется - Бредом.

Comment: @Shrek, мы друг друга не понимаем.

Comment: ;) по-этому мы и не работаем вместе @Construct  :)

Просто редактить комменты не нужно и тогда все будет понятнее. ;)
Мысль излагать нужно сразу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это жесть

```
$query = queryMysql("SELECT id FROM clients WHERE group_id = '$group'");
```

Кто когда нибудь видел функцию **queryMysql**??

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM clients WHERE group_id = '".$group."'");// долго буду писать всем, что добавьте вы **".$VALUE."** чтобы точно запрос прошел, чтобы переменная подставилась.
```

Обычно пишут так

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // СТРОКА 20
    $id = $row['id'];
    $res = mysqlquery("UPDATE `clients` SET `group_id` = '0' WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");// не нужно никаких **;** в запросе!
}
```

Теперь об ошибке.

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied
> argument is not a valid MySQL result
> resource in
> W:\domains\base\www\core\mods\groups\deletegroup.php
> on line 20

Смотрим весь код

```
$group = clear($_GET['id']);
$query = queryMysql("SELECT id FROM clients WHERE group_id = '$group'");

while ($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // СТРОКА 20
    $id = $c['id'];
    $query = queryMysql("UPDATE `clients` SET `group_id` = '0' WHERE `id` = '$id';");
}
```

Нет ничего в глаза не бросается? А мне бросается, когда пишут небольшой бред и неправильно используют переменные.

```
$query = queryMysql("SELECT id FROM clients WHERE group_id = '$group'");
while ($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // СТРОКА 20
 $query = queryMysql("UPDATE `clients` SET `group_id` = '0' WHERE `id` = '$id';");
```

Ничего похожего в строчках нет?
Правильно есть переменная **query** которая должна быть только в начале, в цикле её быть не должно, а точнее должна быть другая.

Поясняю русским языком.
До цикла вытаскиваем данные, начинаем пробегать по ним в цикле, и в первой же итерации у нас данные меняются, причем аж целой структурой меняются! и мускул правильно пишет ошибку.

**ps.  Вот такие ошибки, кстати, сложно отлавливать!**

Comment: > Кто когда нибудь видел функцию
> queryMysql?

Видел! Показываю :D

    function queryMysql($q) { return mysql_query($q); }

Comment: Круто!

Я в глаза не видел, вот и спрашиваю :)

Да велосипеды изобретают даже в 21 веке, и нафига такая функция нужна? Ну так на вскидку? дополнительные байты кода, чтобы начальство дала больше бабла за эти строки? Ну так к примеру? Или эта функция откуда-то из головы у тебя?

Comment: Да я сам прекрасно понимаю что в этом нет особого смысла... Кучу раз видел таког рода велосипеды...

Comment: Было бы так я бы еще понял, велосипед, но хоть выведет если что ошибку, да и запрос покажет. Использовал с своей старой CMS в классе работы с БД
    
    
    function queryMysql($q,$show=false) 
    { 
      if($show) echo "Query is <br />".$q."<br />";// показ запроса.
      $result = mysql_query($query, $this->link) or $this->error();// доп функция
       return $result;
    }
    function error(){
      if ($this->print_errors && $err = mysql_error()) echo "$err<br>\r\n";
    }

Comment: Вот та функция:
function queryMysql($query) {
 $query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 return $query;
}
За ответ спасибо, но заметил раньше чем вы ответили))
P.S. Я новичок в PHP, поэтому и бред

Answer (score 0):

Поле "group_id" какого типа? Если целого, то зачем кавычки?

```
 $query = queryMysql("SELECT id FROM clients WHERE group_id = $group");
```

Comment: Это не решает проблему

Answer (score 0):

В ответе `$query` может не находиться ни одной строки, поэтому `fetch_assoc` не может его обработать. Советую перед `fetch_assoc` поставить проверку `if ($result[0])`. Как раз в этом `$result[0]` может лежать `false`. Можно `mysql_num_rows` проверять на ноль.

Answer (score 0):

```
$group = clear($_GET['id']); //допустим clear это самописная функция очистки
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM clients WHERE group_id = '$group'");

while ($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `clients` SET `group_id` = '0' WHERE `id` = '$c[id]'");
}
```

- **$c[id]** - вот так пишутся элементы массива в двойных кавычках.
- При обновлении, вставке, удалении особо и не нужно загонять это в переменную. Тем более в эту же, что сейчас служит для обработки.

И да вновь мы все разом будем повторять, пора переходить на PDO (или mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего так:

```
UPDATE `clients`
SET `group_id` = '0'
WHERE `id` IN (SELECT id FROM clients WHERE group_id = '$group')
```

Один запрос работает быстрее чем несколько маленьких, особенно id-шек больше 10...